# Bootstrap Tab with VueJS 1.0.28 not working properly while working with Vue 1.0.18

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I had implemented tab activating based on operation performed and response from backend.

In Html

```
a.nav-link[data-toggle="tab" href="#answered" role="tab" :class="{ active: isActive('answered') }"
a.nav-link[data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab" :class="{ active: isActive('all') }"
```

In Js (In a function. after adding answer in `all` tab, I need to active the `answered` tab.)

```
this.questionTab = _.assign({}, this.questionTab, { activeTab: 'answered' })
```

Function `isActive`.

```
methods: {
  isActive: function(tab) {
    return this.questionTab.activeTab === tab;
  }
}
```

The same implementation was working fine with `VueJS 1.0.18`
But After updating it to `1.0.28` it's stopped working.

Basically what I face is once it's have `active` class, and change value of `questionTab.activeTab` in js (not by `click`), it's not removing the `active` class from other tabs even if the condition return false.

I've tried with `v-bind:class="{ active: isActive('all') }"` but didn't get success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `computed` properties in this case, it will be re-computed when data changed

```
computed: {
  isActive () {
    return (tab) => this.positionTab.activeTab === tab
  }
}
```

If above code not work, you can separate to 2 computed properties

```
a.nav-link[data-toggle="tab" href="#answered" role="tab" :class="{ active: isActiveAnswer }"
a.nav-link[data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab" :class="{ active: isActiveAll }"
```

and js

```
computed: {
  isActiveAnswer () {
    return this.positionTab.activeTab === 'answered'
  },
  isActiveAll () {
    return this.positionTab.activeTab === 'all'
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the syntax of first computed property. Can you please suggest me how exactly it should be?

Comment: Are you able to use ES6? First snippet is just my idea. I'm not sure 100% it will work. You should go with second snipper.